# Split PDF document from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

I would like to extract page ranges from a PDF document into a new PDF document using the command line in Linux. Note that:

- [PDFtk - The PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) fails for me with:

```
$ pdftk input.pdf cat 1 verbose output output.pdf
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   input.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

From [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.pdf/c/NE9RtbYfJvE):

> You (should) know that Pdftk is nothing more than a very old version of
> iText (a Java-PDF library) compiled with GCJ and extended with some
> command line functionality.
>
> The keywords in the above statement are "VERY OLD".

- [Multivalent](https://multivalent.sourceforge.net/) also fails:

```
$ java -classpath /path/to/Multivalent20091027.jar tool.pdf.Split -page 1 input.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tool/pdf/Split
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tool.pdf.Split
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: tool.pdf.Split.  Program will exit.
```

Turns out, this is a bit of a tricky software: even if it's on SourceForge, and says [here](https://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/index.html) that

> Practical Thought generously provides these tools for free use on the command line

However, [here](https://multivalent.sourceforge.net/download.html) it says:

> The browser is open source. The document tools are a free bonus and not open source.

Which finally clarifies the comment from [conversion - Gluing (Imposition) PDF documents - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465271/gluing-imposition-pdf-documents/466110#466110):

> All releases of Multivalent linked from the official sourceforge site are missing the tools package.

(*edit: there seems to be an old Multivalent version with the tools included, see the SO link; but as it looks somewhat like abandonware, I'd rather not use it*)

Finally, I'd like to avoid tools that are essentially front ends for LaTeX like [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam).

Are there any options for such a PDF splitting command line tool under Linux?

Comment: [Qpdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF) can split PDFs. For example, to split a PDF into groups of two pages, do: `qpdf --split-pages=2 in.pdf out-%d.pdf`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486231/split-a-pdf-file-into-another-two-pdf-files-using-qpdf) for more. To extract a range of pages, 2 to 5 in this example: `qpdf --empty --pages in.pdf 2-5 -- out.pdf`, see also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf#672001).

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Why is this a comment and not a top-rated answer?

Answer (score 100):

I find pdfseparate very convenient to split ranges into individual pages. You can extract all pages into files named `output-page1.pdf`, `output-page2.pdf`, like this,

```
pdfseparate input.pdf output-page%d.pdf
```

And you can extract pages 1 - 5 of `input.pdf` by using the first-page and last-page flags, `-f 1 -l 5`,

```
pdfseparate -f 1 -l 5 input.pdf output-page%d.pdf
```

If you want to recombine them into page ranges, for example pages 1-3 in one document and pages 4-5 in another, you can use the companion program, pdfunite, as follows:

```
pdfunite output-page1.pdf output-page2.pdf output-page3.pdf final-pages1-3.pdf
pdfunite output-page4.pdf output-page5.pdf final-pages4-5.pdf
```

I believe theese tools are part of poppler and may already be installed on your system.

Comment: Great solution, but: The resulting file size of the split results can sometimes be identical to the whole file. A solution to this is found in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1321515/splitting-pdf-files-using-pdfseparate-poppler#comment2160189_1321515). In my experience, a pdf file created with pdflatex that contained many images using the \includepdf{} command have caused this problem. The solution in the linked comment works great.

Comment: Quote from the comment linked by @Ok_Letsdothis. << [F]irst, "optimiz[e]" the PDF with Ghostscript: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=doc-compressed.pdf doc.pdf`, after which `pdfseparate` lead [sic] to the expected size reduction. >>

Comment: Probably not too useful to write your sample command such that it extracts 1-5. That's going to be arbitrary to users that find this page, which are far more likely to want **all** the pages.

Comment: +1 because `pdfseparate` comes preinstalled with TeX Live for me

Answer (score 24):

Using pdftk 2.02 worked for me on debian, but I think it should work for you too.

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 2-4 output out1.pdf
```

For a general case where you have to split a single pdf to multiple files I could not find a way with pdftk, so I'm using a Bash script.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `pdfjam` tool with the syntax

```
pdfjam <input-file> <page-ranges> -o <output-file>
```

and an example of page ranges would be

```
3,67-70,80
```

<sup>Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79623 by Vincent Nivoliers</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I'll put this as an answer, so as not to clog the question: here is a related link on unix.se:

- [command line - Split pages in pdf - Unix and Linux - Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf);

... and the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf/12483#12483) uses a Python script with PyPDF (but that answer implements a split of one page into two - and that script thus needs to be modified for page ranges, for it to work as asked in OP).

EDIT: I just found this: [Stapler - A python utility for manipulating PDF docs based on pypdf (Page 3) / Community Contributions / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=772678); which is, apparently "[A small utility making use of the pypdf library to provide a (somewhat) lighter alternative to pdftk](https://github.com/fwenzel/stapler)" (note that the mailing list notes some problems with it, however)...

- there is also [PDF-Shuffler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) [based on pypdf](http://blog.mpathirage.com/2010/01/16/merging-pdf-files-in-linux-using-pypdf/); but that one is GUI only - does not have a command line mode...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pdfly`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfly/):

- **Installation**: `pip install pdfly` and [more](https://pdfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html)
- **Usage**: `pdfly cat in.pdf 2:4 -o out.pdf` and [more](https://pdfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/subcommand-cat.html)

Some details:

```
 Page ranges refer to the previously-named file. A file not followed by a page
 range means all the pages of the file.
 PAGE RANGES are like Python slices.
 Remember, page indices start with zero.
 Page range expression examples:

    :     all pages.
    -1    last page.
    22    just the  23rd page.
    :-1   all but the last page.
    0:3   the first   three pages.
    -2    second-to-last page.
    :3    the first      three pages.
    -2:   last two pages.
    5:    from the sixth page onward.
    -3:-1 third & second to last.

 The third, "stride" or "step" number is also recognized.

    ::2       0 2 4 ... to the end.
    3:0:-1    3 2 1 but not 0.
    1:10:2    1 3 5 7 9
    2::-1     2 1 0.
    ::-1      all  pages in reverse order.
```