# Splitting pdf files using pdfseparate (poppler)

Tags: linux, pdf

I'm trying to burst a multipage pdf file using pdfseparate

```
pdfseparate "name.pdf" out-%d.pdf
```

But the individual pages are coming out the same size as the entire original full file.

The viewer displays the correct individual page, and no other, but it seems like the original full file is hidden somewhere in these very large files.

How do I get `pdfseparate` to work properly?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what "name.pdf" does differently from other pdf-files to make `pdfseparate` fail. Find some other pdf where `pdfseparate` works, open both in a text editor which can handle potentially large files (e.g. emacs), read up on the pdf format (objects, page tree), inspect "name.pdf" for any oddities wrt. the page tree, while comparing with the other file.

Comment: That's something that happens quite commonly with PDF splitters. In short, the original file probably has resources (fonts, images) that the pages are sharing (imagine the same font used in every page of the doc), those resources are needed in each of the resulting file so the same font is copied in every output file, so there probably is nothing wrong in `pdfseparate`. It's explained in more details here https://pdfsam.org/pdf-format/i-split-my-pdf-but-the-resulting-files-are-so-big/1910/

Comment: Had the same problem. Solved it by first "optimizing" the PDF with Ghostscript: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=doc-compressed.pdf doc.pdf`, after which `pdfseparate` lead to the expected size reduction.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old (rather ancient) question, and this can be removed if it breaks some rule or needs more details. But I was having the same problem and could not find an answer. After trying some solutions, I solved my problem using *poppler-utils*. So I leave it here to others.

First use *pdftocairo -pdf PDF-file [output-file]* to convert the original PDF to PDF using Cairo (this removed the hyperlinks in the original text). Then use the *pdfseparate* to extract the pages you want and *pdfunite* to build your PDF. In my case this reduced the size from 30 MB per page to something 250-300k per page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is helpful.