# How to save each page of a PDF file into separate files, and name them from text file of file names

Tags: command-line, pdf, script

I have a large PDF file, as well as a text file of file names. I'd like to use the command line to make/save one new PDF file for each page in file.pdf *and* name them with the file names in names.txt. The text file could be comma-delimited or other to suit.

Does anyone know how to do this from the command line?

Comment: You can extract single pages with `pdfly`: https://superuser.com/a/1807735/64857 . Renaming shouldn't be that hard. `pdfly` can also tell you how many pages there are.

Comment: If you're open to Python scripting it's even easier: Just use Python and the `pypdf` library (used by pypdf)